# Windows 8 App - Loading an external Page

Tags: windows-8, winjs

Is there a way to load an external page within a WinJS Windows 8 App? I wanted to load something similar to the following; 
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the external page in an iframe, which will load that page in the web context (giving it different access than pages you might load that are part of your app).

Check [How to link to external web pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780594.aspx) for a full discussion of the various options.

Comment: Thanks Jim, that answered my question!